# Is there a good inline solution to add up without going above a defined value?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

For some reasons i need to reduce the size of my application, and i'm pretty sure there is a way to free room. So, is there a smarter way to do this without making usage of an if ?

```
currentMoney = 46;
maximumMoney = 100;
moneyIncome  = 72;

currentMoney = currentMoney + moneyIncome;

if (currentMoney > maximumMoney)
    currentMoney = maximumMoney;
```

Comment: And your application is written in all those four languages? Wow, must be hard to maintain!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is tag spamming.

Comment: Tag the language your application is written in, not all the ones you've heard about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a minimum function, for example in javascript:

```
currentMoney = Math.min(currentMoney + moneyIncome, maximumMoney);
```

or C#:

```
currentMoney = Math.Min(currentMoney + moneyIncome, maximumMoney);
```

Comment: `Math.Max` just returns `(val1>=val2)?val1:val2`, and `?:` is syntactic sugar for `if`. But on the other hand, OP just wants to reduce the "size", and using `Math.Max` *is* less to write...

Comment: @Corak -- Yeah i know that, but this is the shortest way i can imagine this code to be. You just cannot achieve this goal without any comparison. And the question was to shorten the code... it is shorter :D

Comment: In my case its `Math.min(currentMoney + moneyIncome, maximumMoney);` but thanks anyway.

Comment: Of cause min, my bad. Changed the answer accordingly